# strange function-like syntax in c and c++

Tags: c++, c

The following compiles:

```
main()
{
    int(asdf);

}
```

It seems this is some strange kind of declaration. I have tried to find code like this, but was unable to. Could someone explain?

Comment: This simply declares an `int` variable named `asdf`. Just like in regular math expressions `a=b` means the same thing as `a=(b)`.

Comment: and the code isn't valid C++, nor is it valid current C

Comment: You may also be surprised with the valid syntax 3[arr] where arr is some array or pointer, int arr[5] for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the line

```
int(asdf);
```

is equivalent to

```
int asdf;
```

which obviously declares an ordinary local variable named `asdf`.

But you can put parentheses around various parts of the declarator, whether you need to or not.  So it's just the same if you write

```
int asdf;
```

or

```
int (asdf);
```

or

```
int ((asdf));
```

Parentheses are allowed in declarators because, sometimes, they're necessary in order to make a significant distinction.  For example,

```
int *ap[10];
```

declares an array of 10 pointers, while

```
int (*pa)[10];
```

declares a pointer to an array.

Comment: Thank you! I see it now.